# Fluent NHibernate with DB2 problem

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a project that is using Fluent NHibernate. When I try to use the DB2Configuration to connect to a DB2 database I receive the following error when trying to build the SessionFactory:

"The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly IBM.Data.DB2 could not be found. "

The assembly that is included in my install of IBM Client Access V6R1 has a name of "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll" and not "IBM.Data.DB2". Am I missing something that I am not aware of? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because NHibernate looks for the assembly and the namespaces of the "old" IBM .NET provider (IBM.Data.DB2), and you have the new data provider. [This thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=961161) might clarify it a bit more. I modified NHibernate source code to make it search for the new namespaces as suggested in the link, but then ran into other problems and decided to look for other options. So I don't have the solution, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did exactly what that forum post told me to do and everything is working great.....what was the issue you were running into?

Comment: Nice to hear that=) It's been a while and I don't really remember the issue. Now that it's more curious why it didn't work for me, I might retry and post the results. Thanks for asking.